# The fastest way to subset selected columns from a dataset with R

Tags: r

I have `df1` containing one row of variables that I need and I have `df2`, which has more variables and many rows. I just want to extract the columns from `df2` that exist in `df1`, what is the simplest and fastest way to do it? I am currently running a `for loop` but its very slow and I think there must be an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `intersect`

```
subdf2 <- df2[intersect(names(df1), names(df2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the infix operator `%in%` is faster.

```
names(df2)[names(df2) %in% names(df1)]
```

Tested with package `microbenchmark`.

```
mb <- microbenchmark(
  Intersect = intersect(names(df1), names(df2)),
  In = names(df2)[names(df2) %in% names(df1)]
)
print(mb, unit = 'relative', order = 'median')
#Unit: relative
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#        In 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
# Intersect 5.536585 5.335227 3.530118 4.497696 5.053942 1.339408   100
```

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)
df1 <- as.data.frame(as.list(1:10))
names(df1) <- sprintf("Col%d", c(1:3, 6:10, 14, 15))
df2 <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(1e2, sample(20, 10))))
names(df2) <- sprintf("Col%d", c(1:5, 7:10, 12))
```